# Passing data from activity a to activity b then back to activity a

Tags: android

I would like to ask how to pass value from fragment a to activity B then back to the fragment. i tried using bundle to pass the value but it will give the wrong data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the data from activity B to activity A use the code

In activity B

```
Intent intent = new Intent ();
intent.putExtra ("string_1", "hello");
intent.putExtra ("string_2", "world");
intent.putExtra ("int_1", 1000);
intent.putExtra ("long_1", 2000l);
activity.setResult (Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish()
```

So in Activity A code will be

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        String string_1 = intent.getStringExtra ("string_1", "");
        String string_2 = intent.getStringExtra ("string_2", "");
        int int_1 = intent.getIntExtra ("int_1", 0);
        long long_1 = intent.getLongExtra ("long_1", 0);
    }
}
```

So now you got the data in A. 
So by using the method defined in fragment you can send the data to the target fragment

like say

In fragment if you define

```
public void refreshFragment(String s1)  {

// here s1 will be the data you send from activity Q
}
```

Hope this helps