# How to pass data to a previous activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having the following issue. I have `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`. I have some radio buttons in `ActivityA` and the user can select them. `ActivityB` is accessed trough `ActivityA` so when I press a button I go to `ActivityB`. In `ActivityB` I do some calculations and I want to return the result to `ActivityA` but save the changes made in `ActivityA` before going to `ActivityB`.

If I use `finish()` I return to `ActivityA` and the selected buttons are saved but the result from `ActivityB` is not passed to `ActivityA`.

I want to know is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplication of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124548/how-to-pass-the-values-from-one-activity-to-previous-activity.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/22460381/1078003

Answer (score 2):

Start `Activity B` using `startActivityForResult()` and pass the value from `Activity B` to `Activity A` using `setResult()` and retrieve that result from `onActivityResult()` method.

As example....

In `ActivityA.java`...

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);    
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

In `ActivityB.java`...when sent your result back to `ActivityA`...

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("result", YourResult);
setResult(1, i);
finish();
```

Now, in `ActivityA`, retrieve the result as below...

```
@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

  if(resultCode == 1)
  {
     String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
  } 
}
```